# Electron: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I've started to use boilerplate from [here](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate).
First launch and I get `Electron: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`.

What might be causing an issue like this?

**EDIT**

When trying to do this:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
console.log(app);
```

My terminal returns the app object, but my chrome console returns `undefined`

Comment: Silly question but did you run `npm install` or `yarn` to fetch dependencies?

Comment: I did! (I've also added an edit to my post)